# how can I while using dplyr::mutate code a range of numbers?

Tags: r, dplyr

I wanted to ask if someone knows how to solve my problem:

```
` master1<- master %>%
  mutate(underweight=BMI<18.5,
         normal=BMI%in%c(18.5,24.9),
         overweight=BMI%in%c(25,29.9),
         obese=BMI%in%c(30,34.9),
         extreme=BMI>35) `
```

I want tp create new kind of columns.. for underweight and extreme its working but for normal, overweight and obese, I guess I'm coding the wrong range of numbers...

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with `dput` and expected output

Comment: `%in%` is for exact matches. I am guessing you are looking for `dplyr::between()`

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%in%` will check only exact values.  As these are floating point numbers, it may also not match.  Here, we may need comparison operators (`<`, `>` with `&`) or use `between`

```
library(dplyr)
master1 <- master %>%
     mutate(underweight = BMI < 18.5,
        normal = between(BMI, 18.5, 24.9),
         overweight = between(BMI, 25, 29.9),
         obese = between(BMI, 30, 34.9),
         extreme = BMI > 35))
```

Answer (score 1):

I've created a reproducible example (reprex) to help explain and I've used the package {dplyr}:

```
library(dplyr)

# Create data frame for 34 subjects
# and add a column with random numbers for weight between 15 and 34
master1 <- data.frame(
  subjects = sample(1:34)
) %>% 
mutate(BMI = runif(34, min = 15, max = 34),
     BMI = round(BMI, digits = 1)) # rounds to 1 digit
```

When you recode, it's best to recode to one column, this is known as long form data:

```
# Create a column called category with the labels for the weight groups

master1 <- master1 %>% 
     category = case_when(BMI <=  18.5 ~ "underweight",
                          BMI >= 18.5 & BMI <= 24.9 ~ "normal",
                          BMI >= 25 & BMI <= 29.9 ~ "overweight",
                          BMI >= 30 & BMI <= 34.9 ~ "obese",
                          BMI >= 35 ~ "extreme",
                          TRUE ~ NA_character_ # Just in case anything is # outside of these numbers this will return an NA which means nothing was entered
                          ))
```